# How i can get index and max value in one row and one function? maybe pandas have some special?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know an index and max value from my table per year. How i can get it?

```
per_2016_17_year = bookings[['arrival_date_year', 'arrival_date_month']]\
    .query('arrival_date_year in [2016,2017]')\
    .groupby(['arrival_date_year', 'arrival_date_month'])\
    .agg({ 'arrival_date_month' : 'count'})
    
per_2016_17_year.loc[2016].max()
```

```
arrival_date_month    6203
```

```
per_2016_17_year = bookings[['arrival_date_year', 'arrival_date_month']]\
    .query('arrival_date_year in [2016,2017]')\
    .groupby(['arrival_date_year', 'arrival_date_month'])\
    .agg({ 'arrival_date_month' : 'count'})
    
per_2016_17_year.loc[2016].idxmax()
```

```
arrival_date_month    October
```

in this code i have only value or index but i want them together

here is some data

```
arrival_date_month
arrival_date_year   arrival_date_month  
2016    April   5428
August  5063
December    3860
February    3891
January 2248
July    4572
June    5292
March   4824
May 5478
November    4454
October 6203
September   5394
2017    April   5661
August  4925
February    4177
January 3681
July    5313
June    5647
March   4970
May 6313
```

I try `.idxmax()` and i have only index. I try `.max()` and i have only value. How i can get them together?

Comment: I don't think there's a single function that will return both `idxmax` and `max` at once, but you can always use the value returned from `idxmax` to get the max value just by indexing into the column.

Comment: It'd help to put the data in a format we can use. For details see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Getting the row with max value in Pandas](/q/42234039/4518341). See also [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](/q/17071871/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.